# undefined variable and undefined index php errors

Tags: php, regex

I've been given the task to remove undefined variable and undefined index errors, which i know how to

```
$value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
```

The problem is this is way too time consuming, I predict over 2000 variables, $_GET, $_POST hasn't been set.  So is there a regular expression i can use to set these variables quickly?

How do i do regex to change this `$category = $_GET['c']` to this

`$category = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : ''`?

And how do i do regex to change `if($page or $category or $profile)` to this

`if(isset($page) or isset($category) or isset($profile))`?

This is the best method i can think of by using regex find & replace in Notepad++.  I assume over 2000 PHP variable/index undefined errors.  How do i solve this without turning off errors?

Comment: Not regex, but a simple `for each` loop over the `$_POST`/`$_GET` should work

Answer (score 1):

you should not use regex because it's kind of heavy :) 
if i'm understanding your question right, you can do this like this,
with this approach, it does not matter how many parameters contains POST or GET, you simply filter them through foreach loop and getting clean arrays with parameters, also you can make it a function that returning array.and then you just need to check `if_array_key_exests()` and do your things.

```
 $_POST = ["user"=>"1", "num"=>2];
 $_GET  = ["user" => '', "num"=>1];


//function method
 function filter($array)
 {
   $arr = array();

   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

    if (!empty($val)) {
        $arr[$key] = $val;
    } 
  }

  return $arr;
}
```

without function

```
 $post = array();
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if (!empty($val)) {
            $post[$key] = $val;
        }
 }

 $get = array();
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
         if (!empty($val)) {
             $get[$key] = $val;
         }  
 }
```

Comment: This only works for GET parameters with empty/falsy values. But I think his actual problem is that he does a *code rewrite* to make the code E_STRICT compliant. The legacy code uses $_GET with keys that do not exist (because they are not passed via the query string). So, any loop will not cover those keys, too.

Comment: Mm... if this is ready code, he better need to change him completely and not waste time to change each line else,it's working perfect with the get and also with the post requests. I always do this ,when i'm expecting to a lot of data. He can check in function if array that passed is not empty and then do foreach loop. And return clean array. And after that check array key for what ever he want to do, for example - build sql with only passed valid data, with if statements.

Comment: I think the main problem in the question are those 2000 'undefined' notices. Your technique works, but if he uses it, he had to replace 2000 `if($_GET['c'])` and similar by `if(array_key_exists('c', $get))`, this is why he asked for a RegEx that he can use in his text editor. So I think the intention of his question was mainly how to easily replace all of the erroneous code and not how to validate data in the running application.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, replacing something like

```
(\$\w+)\s*=\s*\$_GET\[['"]?(\w+)['"]?\]\s*;
```

by

```
$1 = isset($_GET['$2']) ? $_GET['$2'] : '';
```

should work.

Regarding the second, I don't know if this is possible with a variable number of variables. This one works for 3 variables, replace

```
if\s*\(\s*\s*(\$\w+)\s+or\s+(\$\w+)\s+or\s+(\$\w+)\s*\)
```

by

```
if (isset($1) or isset($2) or isset($3))
```

You can add another `\s+or\s+(\$\w+)` before the last `\s*` in the search, and add another `or isset($4)` in the replacement for 4 variables etc.

I recommend you to replace them one by one instead of replacing all at once ;-)

Also note that `if ($a)` is not the same as `if (isset($a))`. Consider something like this:

```
// query string is a=0
$a = $_GET['a'];
if ($a) // will be false
if (isset($a)) // will be true
if (!empty($a)) // will be false
```

So, perhaps you want to use `!empty()` instead of `isset()`. This should work without notices, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
resove first issue:
define a function like:
function global_get($key){
    return isset($_GET[$key])?$_GET[$key]:'';
}

then use sed(linux tool) to replace all parts like this(it will modify all the $_GET[.*] of php extension files in your project,so be careful to use this):
find /yourproject -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s/\$_GET\[\([^]]*\)\]/global_get(\1)/" \;

you may modify this command to apply your own demand.


The second issue could be harmful if you use the regex expression because it is hard to make a role rule.so I recommend you to replace manually.
```